# A condition for checking if a field is 'None' is not working as expected

Tags: python, django, if-statement

So I'm running a basic loop that's iterating through a list of items containing a dictionary and I'm filtering the list on the basis of if the selected key !=" " or None. However, the !=" " part seems to be working but the None check is not working.

Here's what I'm trying to say in code form

```
data = [{'Field': 'somevalue', 'Anotherfield': 'somevalue'}, {'Field': 'somevalue', 'Anotherfield': ''}, {'Field': 'somevalue', 'Anotherfield': None}}
datanew = []

for items in data:
  if items['Anotherfield']!= '' or items['Anotherfield'] is None:
    datanew.append(items)
```

What I should be getting is `datanew = [{'Field': 'somevalue', 'Anotherfield': 'somevalue'}]` vs what I'm getting `datanew = [{'Field': 'somevalue', 'Anotherfield': 'somevalue'}, {'Field': 'somevalue', 'Anotherfield': None}]`

I think it's just a simple mistake in the if condition somehow, but I've gone over it a lot of times now and haven't been able to figure it out yet. What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: You're literally saying: "If the field is not an empty string *or if it is None*, append it to the list"… You might want to negate that `is None` check!? `... != '' and ... is not None`

Comment: At this point I should just delete my SO account for asking these stupid questions, but thanks anyway. Learning slowly. You can submit this as an answer btw and I can accept it if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be that you need to use operators to compare.
Try with `items['Anotherfield'] != None:`
You need to write is not or use ' != '
or else it will print out both values because it returns true.

Comment: Note that `... != '' or ... is not None` will always be true. The boolean operator needs to be negated as well.